# Is it possible to access data / record from two (2) microphones in Android devices?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am trying to access, programatically, the data received from 2 microphones on Android devices.
This arises several questions:

1. Are there shipping Android devices with 2 microphones (e.g. for stereo recording)? I know there are devices with 2 microphones for echo cancellation / noise reduction, but as far as I could find they can be accessed as a single microphone for any programatic purpose.
2. Are there devices with a microphone / headphone socket supporting stereo external microphones?
3. Assuming any of the above is positive, is there a way to know what is the currently operating microphone setup?

I will appreciate any response!

Thanks,
Yoav

Answer (score 0):

I only found out that e.g. once you plug in wired headset with microphone it doesn't matter what `AudioSource` you specify in you code - it always give you the audio stream form headset mic. I tried to get access to internal mic using `AudioSource.CAMCORDER` but without luck. I haven't tried with wireless (BT) headset though. However if I plugin headphones (w/o mic) it uses internal microphone. At least this is the outcome on my SGS2 with ICS 4.0. If somebody find a workaround I would be happy to hear as well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried yet, but maybe the Native Developement Tools can allow you to access any microphone you want from low level.

If you want to make things a bit simpler, you could consider using [OpenSL ES for Android](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/opensles/), although i have no idea if it provides low-level microphone control.